# All my Stack Overflow history of answers and reputation disappeared

Tags: support, user-accounts, deleted-accounts, multiple-accounts

I am not sure what's going on, but none of my history is showing... The questions that I answered show my answer, but they show *user********* as the user, rather than my name...

Comment: Do you have a link to one of the posts?

Comment: @Glorfindel https://stackoverflow.com/a/57380361/447356

Comment: OK, I'll try to find a Stack Overflow moderator who can analyze this. You'd normally ask a question like this on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) rather than here, but you don't have the reputation to participate there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like your account was deleted by a site moderator.

Since we (the ordinary users of Stack Exchange) can't see and know any details, and since you don't have account on Stack Overflow itself, I advise to submit a "contact us" form, click "contact" in the footer of any page on any site and choose "Other" then explain what happened.

In the meanwhile it's better not to create new accounts on that site, until you sort out what happened.